# How do I access all values from nested JSON Array?

Tags: arrays, json, object, react-native, jsx

Here is my JSON array:

```
    [{"id":"11",
"first_name":"John",
"last_name":"Doe",
"username":"Username1234",
"email":"example1426@gmail.com",
"who":"Person",
"user_images":[{"id":"114",
"username":"Hannah_L123",
"images":"resized_1522-20131219-creativity.jpg","date":"12\/04\/2017"}]}]
```

I don't use the first array, but I do use the second array like this:

```
  user_image:  responseJson[0].user_images.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0), unprogress: new Animated.Value(1) }))
```

I just want to access all the `username` from `user_images` that is already mapped. Trying these did not work: `{this.state.user_image.username}`//Undefined `{this.state.user_image["username"]}`//Undefined

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I found out how to do it: `this.state.user_image[0].username`, but how do I `console.log()` all of the data that contains a `username`? I am only logging 3 from the console.

React Native Code:

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/React/user.php')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          user_image:  responseJson[0].user_images.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0), unprogress: new Animated.Value(1) })),
          }, function() {
            const userImagesWithUsername = this.state.user_image.map(item => item.username != undefined);
            console.log(userImagesWithUsername);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: did you use JSON.parse("your json") before trying to access the object?

Comment: No I did not, how do I do that? Because I never had a time where I would need to use `JSON.parase` @slashsharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain all data that contains `username` you can filter the `user_image` Array.

```
const userImagesWithUsername = this.state.user_image.filter(item => item.username != undefined);
```

Comment: thank you, but When I console log this all it does it print the whole list out again.

Comment: If the whole list contains a username field I think it is normal! What do you really want to do?

Comment: I just want all of the `usernames` from that list. Just that without all of the other properties, if it's possible.

Comment: Ah okay! Then just add `.map(item => item.username)` and it’ll return a array of username

Comment: fetch('https://www.example.com/React/user.php')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
              user_image:  responseJson[0].user_images.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0), unprogress: new Animated.Value(1) })),
              }, function() {
                const userImagesWithUsername = this.state.user_image.map(item => item.username != undefined);
                console.log(userImagesWithUsername);
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
          });

Comment: Don’t replace filter by map but add ma after filter like .filter(item => item.username != undefined).map(item => item.username)